# Loading modules into Client script called from a custom button

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I've got some code in a javascript AMD module. If I create a ClientScript which references it and deploy it, the code runs fine when called from the ClientScript event. But if I call the exact same function from a custom button click event, it bombs with an Unexpected error inside require.js (see the end of the post for console outputs).

Here's the ClientScript code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType ClientScript
 * @NModuleScope public
 */

'use strict'
require.config({
    paths: {
        'iceUtil': 'SuiteScripts/ieCommon/iceUtil'
    }
});

define(['N/log', 'iceUtil'], function (https, iceUtil) {
    function calculateConfigurations() {
        console.log('calculateConfigurations: before native log call');
        log.debug({
            title: 'calculateConfigurations',
            details: 'nothing'
        })

        console.log('calculateConfigurations: before iceUtil log call');
        iceUtil.logDebug('calculateConfigurations - iceUtil log', 
            'nothing');
    }

    function fieldChanged() {
        iceUtil.logDebug('pageInit', 'begining client event');
        calculateConfigurations();
        iceUtil.logDebug('pageInit', 'ending client event');
    }

    return {
        calculateConfigurations: calculateConfigurations
        , fieldChanged: fieldChanged
    }
});
```

iceUtil.js really just wraps the native NetSuite log functionality.

This works fine and all logs show when called from the fieldChanged event firing.

But if I wire it up to a custom button, using the following code, only the first `console.log('recordId: ' + recordId);` call runs. The first call to `iceUtil.logDebug` bombs.

Here's the code which wires up the button:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */
define(["N/log", "../ieCommon/iceUtil"], function (log, iceUtil) {

    function addCalcConfigsButton(context) {
        if(context.type==context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
            context.form.clientScriptFileId = 6222;
            //context.form.clientScriptModulePath = 'SuiteScripts/ieOppMetrics/clientCalculateConfigurations.js'; // This also works
            context.form.addButton(
                {
                    id : 'custpage_buttonid',
                    label : 'Calculate Configurations',
                    functionName : 'calculateConfigurations'
                }
            );
            iceUtil.logDebug("addCalcConfigButton - iceUtil log", 
                "Button added.");

            log.debug({
                title: 'addCalcConfigButton - native log',
                details: 'Button added.'
            });
        } 
    }

    return {
        beforeLoad : addCalcConfigsButton
    };
});
```

Here's the console output from this code when it's called from the fieldChanged event and works (the log messages also show in the NS Execution Log):

```
[Log] calculateConfigurations: before native log call
[Log] calculateConfigurations: before iceUtil log call
```

Here's the console output from pressing the button and fails (there are no log messages in the NS Execution Log):

```
[Log] calculateConfigurations: before native log call
[Error] UNEXPECTED_ERROR: Unexpected Error
    onError (bootstrap.js:150)
    onError (NsRequire.js:645)
    check (NsRequire.js:994)
    enable (NsRequire.js:1251)
    init (NsRequire.js:882)
    (anonymous function) (NsRequire.js:1547)
```

Comment: In your client script you are requiring `N/log` dependency but its name in the definition function is `https`. `log` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't a module loading problem at all; it was a problem in the `N/log` code specifically and the JS environment when getting called from the different places (NS client event vs. arbitrary JS function from a custom button).

When `log.debug()` is being called from the button, the JS environment has the following variables defined and with values:
`NLScriptIdForLogging` and `NLDeploymentIdForLogging`, but these were not defined when `log.debug()` was successfully called from the NS client event.

If you run the following before calling `log.debug()`, it will run successfully from the button code:

```
delete NLScriptIdForLogging;
delete NLDeploymentIdForLogging;
```

I'm not sure what these are trying to do, so I'm just checking for them and skipping the `log.debug()` call (or routing it to the JS console if it's there).

This seems like a NS bug. Does anyone know how I can report it?

Answer (score 0):

"The first call to iceUtil.logDebug bombs." This is incredibly vague. Post the actual Error output (most importantly the main error and the first line in the stack trace that references your own code) to give people some hints where in your code to look for your bug.

Even without the actual error, I'd say this line looks incredibly suspicious:

```
functionName : 'calculateConfigurations(' + context.newRecord.id + ')'
```

I don't know what the underlying code is that processes your call to `context.form.addButton`, but I suspect from the property name `functionName` that the only valid value to give it is a `[String]` containing the name of a function within the scope of `context`.

Instead you are trying very hard to do some sort of dynamic function creation that probably has zero meaning to the `addButton()` method you are calling.

Where did `context.form.addButton` come from? It is not native js and has no obvious reference from your code example. Is that method provided by a library you haven't mentioned?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the original post with the console output and error stack trace, and also removed the passed parameter as you suggest, but am still having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `functionName` property of  `addButton` is only expecting the *name* of the function. I don't believe you can invoke the function and pass parameters like that.

Your click handler will need to read the ID of the current record either from the `context` or by using the `N/currentRecord` module from NetSuite.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I changed it to not pass the param (both with and without parens) and it still bombs in the same way. (BTW, I got that technique from a comment in [this blog post](https://ursuscode.com/netsuite-tips/suitescript-2-0-quickstart-samples/#comment-3159860869)).

Comment: FYI, I updated the original post with simpler code which doesn't try to pass the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely having an issue due to the update to the require Object Configuration in NetSuite. It would be a bit much to type out so please just refer to the NetSuite documentation [here](https://system.na2.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4599733337.html&whence=) for the details. If that does not give enough context for your situation refer to the 2017.2 release notes, pages 67 and 68. Hope this helps.